# Populating my jquery autocomplete with contents of an ajax call to cakephp

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, cakephp-2.1

I have an input field that I'm turning into a jqueryUI autocomplete:

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: mylist
 });
```

The mylist variable is just a string in the array format `['Value1','Value2,'Blah']` which i originally just hardcoded into the script.

Now I want the mylist variable to be the result of an ajax call to a function in my cakephp app. The function is basically as follows, it just grabs all the data as a list, and json encodes it.

```
public function source() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $countries=$this->Country->find('list',array('fields'=>'Country.country'));
    ChromePhp::log($countries);
    echo json_encode($countries);
}
```

This outputs:

```
{"1":"Afghanistan","2":"Albania ","3":"Algeria ","5..
```

My issue is getting the output of this function, (which ends up in the ajax success callback as 'data') into the correct format to place into the options array of the autocomplete.

I can get as far as console logging each value, but I'm stumped. Basically clutching at straws at the correct syntax.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/source/",
    success: function(data){
        /*
        magic array string creation code would go here instead of my code below...
        */
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
        console.log('data',data);


    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocomplete plugin can do a lot of the work for you if you give it things in the right format.

I would start by re-indexing the `$countries` variable to start from 0. You can use the `array_values()` function for that:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($countries));
```

This should give you the JSON in the format of:

```
['Afghanistan','Albania','Algeria',...]
```

Then you can change the source property in the autocomplete code to be a url for your source action.

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: "/your_controller/source"
});
```

The autocomplete plugin won't filter the results for you, instead a query string is added to the url with a `term` field (e.g. /your_controller/source?term=foo) so you need to modify your `find()` method to use this.

```
$countries = $this->Country->find('list', array(
    'fields' => 'Country.country',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Country.country LIKE' => $this->request->query['term'] . '%'
    )
));
```

You can read more about the different types the `source` option can accept in the autocomplete on the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

Comment: Exactly why this site is my favourite development site of all time :) Thanks.